# Where does provisioning profiles live in my iPhone XS?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, provisioning-profile

[Apple Developer Program Information](https://developer.apple.com/programs/information/Apple_Developer_Program_Information_8_12_15.pdf) says:

> A Development Provisioning Profile **must be installed on each device** on
> which you wish to run your application code.
>
> Each Development
> Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development
> Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an App ID.

So where are provisioning profiles in my iPhone XS?

Can I see them?

Can I download them?

Can I beam them to any other device via bluetooth? airdrop? email?

Comment: “Can I beam them to any other device” LOL Obviously if you could do that you would break through the entire security system that Apple has devised.

Comment: @matt, well then how do I know if any profisioning profiles are installed in my iPhone if can't find them manually?

Comment: If you can run the app on your device, it is because you have the provisioning profile.

Comment: Please see @Paulw11's answer below.  Unfortunately, matt's answer and comments portray an incorrect impression of provisioning profiles use and behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended for security reasons offcourse, but if you see yourself in the position that you want to distribute your file ad-hoc onair via 3rd-party software (e.g. installonair.com): their download file does not include the provisioning profile and won't let you download the app.

In my case downloading the correct provisioning profile and sharing it via airdrop it installed the provisioning profile on the ipad. **You cannot see it, but is there.** With the provisioning profile installed manually, it is now possible to download the app via 3rd party software.

Comment: after some experience, discovered that the provisioning profile is included in the build, but the 3rd-party software does not install it for you. This means that if you need to update an provision profile with an extra UDID for example,  you need to distribute and sign a new build and install te new provisioning profile manually.

Answer (score 2):

The development provisioning profile is contained in the application bundle that is installed on the iOS device (typically using Xcode, but you can also use ad-hoc distribution methods).

1. You can't see them.  There is no settings screen that shows the development apps installed on your phone.
2. You can't download them (well, you can download the app bundle using Xcode, but if you have Xcode you could just recompile your app).
3. You can't send a provisioning profile to another device from the device. Even if you could, it wouldn't really serve any purpose because the provisioning profile includes a list of authorised device identifiers and some arbitrary device won't be on the list.

Comment: While you can't do direct device to device transfers of provisioning profiles, another option for installing provisioning profiles on devices directly would be to use mobile device management (MDM) software to push profiles to managed devices.  Probably not what the OP was looking for, but could be an option if the OP is trying to manage this in an enterprise setting.

Comment: Also, for #1, you can't see them on the device anymore (you used to be able to).  However, you can see installed provisioning profiles in the Devices window in Xcode when your device is connected.

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning profile is installed when you correctly and legally install the app. You cannot see it. It is there to enforce security. It is your warrant to run this particular app on this particular device.

> Can I beam them to any other device

Obviously not; if you could do that you would break through the entire security system that Apple has devised.

Comment: This is bad that docs do not explain that. Because I imagine provisioning profile as something like a file with a set of characters, like public or private keys.

Comment: That is what it is. You can see it on your computer.

Comment: Not really true.  Beaming a provisioning profile to another device would do nothing to Apple's security model because the provisioning profile contains a list of devices on which applications that match the bundle ID can run.  "Beaming" it to another device not listed would result in the application not being able to run.